# reactjs routing to a specific section of a different page

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, react-router

from page 1 I am trying to route to a specific section of page 2.
I tried to use the hash value in the Link component but it did not work 
`` <Link to={ {pathname: `/page2`, hash: `#sectionID`}} > ``
I even used this package `react-router-hash-link` with no success.

I always end up at the top of page 2.

any help

Answer (score 0):

Check This link for full explanation;
[Hash link scroll functionality for React Router](https://reactjsexample.com/hash-link-scroll-functionality-for-react-router/), and here is example that will scroll to the component when you open it: [baz#section-three](http://react-router-hash-link.rafrex.com/baz#section-three), another one [baz#section-two](http://react-router-hash-link.rafrex.com/baz#section-two)